# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{\sin(2n-1)\theta}{(2n-1)^2}$ with Abel's limit theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an exercise from a complex analysis course for physics students:

> Evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{\sin(2n-1)\theta}{(2n-1)^2},\quad\theta \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}].$$
> Hint: use $$\ln(1-z) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n},\quad |z|<1$$ and Abel's limit theorem.

### My attempt:

Define
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)^2}.$$
Then formally,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{\sin(2n-1)\theta}{(2n-1)^2} = \operatorname{Im} f(e^{i\theta}).$$
We have
$$zf'(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^{2n-1}}{2n-1} = \frac{1}{2i}\ln\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}=\arctan z.$$
Then I get stuck. It seems that $\int \frac{\arctan z}{z}\mathrm{d}z$ is not elementary and I'm going nowhere.
One of my classmates tried
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f(e^{i\theta})}{\mathrm{d}\theta} = \frac{1}{2}\ln\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\frac{\pi}{4}i,$$
so $$\frac{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{Im}f(e^{i\theta})}{\mathrm{d}\theta} = \frac{\pi}{4},$$
and since $\operatorname{Im}f(1) = 0$, it follows that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{\sin(2n-1)\theta}{(2n-1)^2} = \operatorname{Im} f(e^{i\theta}) = \frac{\pi}{4}\theta.$$
But this obviously doesn't follow Abel's limit theorem, since the path falls outside the Stolz sector. Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: the result is correct - not sure what's the problem; also you can integrate (carefully) the well known $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{\cos(2n-1)x}{(2n-1)} =\pi/4, -\pi/2 < x <-\pi/2$ (which is straightforward by considering the expansion of the odd extension of $\pi/4$ on $(0, \pi)$ in Fourier series of sines and changing variables $x \to \pi/2-x$)

Comment: @Conrad Yes, I see that this can be solved by Fourier series. But this is an elementary complex analysis course and we've got to the power series, I doubt this is the answer that the teacher wanted. Thanks anyway!

Comment: then maybe you can get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{\cos(2n-1)x}{(2n-1)} =\pi/4$ following the hint but taking the real part of a logarithmic expansion and the limit as $|z| \to 1$; still not sure what is wrong with the solution you propose in the OP

Comment: @Conrad I see what you mean. Problem solved. Thank you!

Comment: @Conrad I think the problem is that when using complex approach, $f(e^{i\theta})$ can only be approached from the interior of the circle $|z| < 1$ but not along the circle $|z| = 1$. Taking the derivative of $\theta$ of the original trigonometric series as you said can avoid this.